VBA Wait to confirm logging in the web page
I wrote a code to direct a user to a login web page and now want to identify if he/she logged in successfully just by page's own login form after clicking "Enter" button, then when a new page opened completely, get the new page document to do some work on it.
url="http: ... /Login"
I can direct user to this url(login page)

With IE
.visible=true
.navigate url
End with

Now here i want a code to wait until user pass the login page successfully and maybe get some kind of signal and proceed running remained code automatically, then get new page document for example by
IE.locationURL

I know what the new url should be, but when i use the above code (for example in a loop) and log in to the page by myself to get url, it gives me the first url of login page again.
